# Prevent set null on delete in Entity Framework database-first

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a ***database-first*** model using Entity Framework 6.2.0 which has the following association:
[image]

As you see, the OnDelete property on both ends is set to `None`. The corresponding relation in SQL server is shown below:
[image]

Although there is no explicit setting to set null on delete, when I try to remove an object from Plannings (primary table), EF sets all foreign key records in the table Waybill to null.

In the same database and model, I have the following foreign key and corresponding association:
[image]
[image]

All circumstances are the same as earlier. But in this case, when I try to remove an object from Products, it fails because of conflict with foreign key constraint (as I expect).

Why these two similar cases have different behavior? How can I completely disable set null on delete in my ***database-first*** model? I know that in ***code-first*** model, we can delete conventions using the following:

```
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
```

But I could not find any way to do this in ***database-first***.

Comment: In database first, you should start with the database... so, how is the `ON DELETE` option defined in database? Is it the same for you examples?

Comment: @grek40 the `ON DELETE` is set to `NO ACTION` (as shown in images)

Comment: did you update your EF model, if you changed the database schema before?

Comment: @mehmetx yes, not only the model was updated, but also the database has not been changed before. I never create relationships with CASCADE option and the mentioned relationship was created with NO ACTION.

Comment: The question was asked more than 3 years ago :). I did not find any solution to make it work. Finally I implemented a check in my application for this specific relationship and throw error if it must not be deleted!